# How many conditions can we add to a CLMonitor from WWDC2023?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, ios17

Apple presented the all-new [Core Location Monitor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clmonitor) at [WWDC 2023](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10147/).
It changes the logic of monitoring for iBeacons with a new approach of adding **CLCondition**-s for monitoring iBeacon values like UUID, major, and minor.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clmonitor/4240034-addconditionformonitoring), I suppose (please do feel free to correct me) is meant to replace current (now [deprecated)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423656-startmonitoring) startMonitoring implementation.

It's a fact that it is impossible to monitor more than 20 regions at once.

**Question:** does the new CLMonitor let us bypass this limit? If not, what's the maximum number of CLConditions we can add to a CLMonitor? I did not have a chance to install Xcode beta and the docs do not say anything about the limits.

Comment: Since a `CLMonitor` is just an actor that delivers a stream of region events, I would assume that the same restrictions apply as have always applied.